# Stored procedure using too many selects?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, database-administration

I recently started doing some performance tuning on a client's stored procedures and i bumped into this chunk of code and could'nt find a way to make it work more efficiently.

```
declare @StationListCount int;
select @StationListCount = count(*) from @StationList;
declare @FleetsCnt int;
select @FleetsCnt=COUNT(*) from @FleetIds;
declare @StationCnt int;
select @StationCnt=COUNT(*) from @StationIds;
declare @VehiclesCnt int;
select @VehiclesCnt=COUNT(*) from @VehicleIds;

declare @TrIds table(VehicleId bigint,TrId bigint,InRange bit);

insert into @TrIds(VehicleId,TrId,InRange)
select t.VehicleID,t.FuelTransactionId,1
from dbo.FuelTransaction t
join dbo.Fleet f on f.FleetID = t.FleetID and f.CompanyID=@ActorCompanyID
where t.TransactionTime>=@From and (@To is null or t.TransactionTime<@To)
and (@StationListCount=0 or exists (select id fRom @StationList where t.FuelStationID = ID))
and (@FleetsCnt=0 or exists (select ID from @FleetIds where ID = t.FleetID))
and (@StationCnt=0 or exists (select ID from @StationIds where ID = t.FuelStationID))
and (@VehiclesCnt=0 or exists (select ID from @VehicleIds where ID = t.VehicleID))
and t.VehicleID is not null
```

the insert command slows the whole procedure and takes 99% of the resources.

[I am not sure but i think these nested loops are referring to the queries inside the where clause](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv9zm.jpg)

I would very much appreciate the help i can get on this.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried joining the tables instead of using exists clause?

Comment: these tables have a single column in them.... joining wont solve it :\

Answer (score 0):

Insert is using only 1 table for vehicle Id so joining other tables doesn't requires.

Comment: the thing is that the join for the 'Fleet' table is to get all the records that has FleedID as null and that the companyID is matched to the fleetID. What about that change : I added it up instead of the join.  
and exists (select FleetId from dbo.Fleet where Fleetid = t.FleetID and CompanyID=@ActorCompanyID)

Comment: Join tables which are required in insert statement. Others are not required.

Comment: This is wrong. If you look at the query you can understand that the join is there for predication. after testing the same query but leaving the join out and using predication in the where clause i got worse performance.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things that you actually should go over and see the performance differences. First of all, as the previous answer suggest you should omit the count(*)-like aggragates as much as possible. If the table is so big, the cost of these functions exponentially increase. You can even think of storing those counts in a seperate table with proper index constraints.

I also suggest you to split the select statement into multiple statements because when you use so many NULL checks, or, and conditions in combinations; your indexes may be bypassed so that your query cost increases a lot. Sometimes, using UNIONs may provide far better performance than using such conditions.

Actually, you should try all these and see what fits your needs

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the declaration of the @table variables, but (assuming the IDs in them are unique) consider communicating this information to the optimizer, IOW add primary key constraints to them.

Also, add the `option(recompile)` to the end of the query.